# Sigma Field on [0,1] generated by the family {Xt: 0<= t <= 1} where Xt = 1t

Tags: measure-theory

I was wondering about the following question:

Describe the $\sigma$-field on [0,1] generated by the family $\{X_{t}: 0 \leq t \leq 1 \}$ where $X_{t} = 1_{t}$.

Overall, I am a bit confused of the idea of a $\sigma$-field generated by a family of random variables. I am not asking for solutions, just wondering if anyone could give me a hint to start the question.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint 1: the $\sigma$-field generated by a family of random variables $X_i : i \in I$ is equal to the $\sigma$-field generated by the collection of events $X_i^{-1}(B)$ where $i$ ranges over the index set and $B$ ranges over all Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.  Now note that $X_t^{-1}(B)$ is either $\emptyset$, $[0,1]$, $\{t\}$, or $[0,1] \setminus \{t\}$.  So you are really considering the $\sigma$-field generated by the singleton sets $\{t\} : t \in [0,1]$ (their complements will automatically be in there too).

Now think about what additional sets must necessarily be in this $\sigma$-field, given that it must be closed under complements and countable unions.  When you can't think of any more, consider the collection of all the sets you have thought of, and try to prove it is a $\sigma$-algebra.  If it is, then you know you indeed have the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the singletons.